# Reference or variable?

Tags: php, variables, reference

Once I pass a variable inside a function as a reference, if I later access it, is it still a reference or..?

Example:

```
function one(){
    $variables = array('zee', 'bee', 'kee');
    $useLater =& $variables;
    two($variables);
}

function two($reference){
    foreach($reference as $variable){
        echo 'reference or variable, that is the question...';
    }
}
```

In function `two();` are the variables here a reference to previously set $variables or a new element is created (in memory, I guess..)?

Plus, one more, is there a way to check if variable is passed by reference or not? (like: `is_reference();`)

Comment: Whatever the answer is: Pass by reference at call time is deprecated.

Comment: @Felix, what is the replacement for "pass by reference" now?

Comment: You can test this pretty easily, OP.

Comment: @Tom: Read the documentation.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see any "passing by reference" here. It's `$ref = &$var; f($ref);` here, not `f(&var);`.

Comment: 'binaryLV I was thinking exactly the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable is only passed by reference (in current versions of PHP), if you explicitly pass it by reference using `&$foo`.

Equally, when declaring a variable to a new variable, such as `$foo = $bar`, $foo will be a reference to $bar until the value changes. Then it is a new copy.

There are lots of ways of **detecting a reference** here, maybe check some of them out. (Why you would need to do this is unknown, but still, it is there).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.spot.php

Answer (score 2):

As defined above the function two will use a new copy of `$refernce`.

To use the original variable you need to define function two like this:

```
function two(&$ref) {
  //> Do operation on $ref;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

variable. look:

```
function one(){
    $variables = array('zee', 'bee', 'kee');
    $useLater =& $variables;
    two($variables);
    var_dump($variables);
}

function two($reference){
    $reference = array();
}
```

gives

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "zee" [1]=> string(3) "bee" [2]=> string(3) "kee" }
```

so changing it in `two()` diesn't change it in `one()`, so it's variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parameter for the function to be a reference, you have to write an & there, too.

Only exception should be objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it out for yourself:

```
<?php

$variables = array('zee', 'bee', 'kee');
one($variables);

foreach($variables as $variable2){
        echo "original: ".$variable2."<br>";
    }


function one(&$variables){

    $useLater =& $variables;
    two($variables);

    foreach($variables as $variable2){
        echo "function one: ".$variable2."<br>";
    }

}

function two(&$reference){
    foreach($reference as $variable){
        echo "function two: ".$variable."<br>";
    }
    $reference[0] = 'lee';
}

?>
```

Now leave out the &-sign and see what happens. You will need to tell PHP explicitly everytime how you intend to pass on the variable in question.